# getting ./coundown 5 to countdown from 5

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, timer, countdown

I have a file named countdown on my computer and I am trying to get it to countdown from what ever the user puts in.

for example ./countdown 5 would cause a 5 second timer to start outputting a "." every second and prints done after 5 seconds.

./countdown 10 would cause a 10 second timer to start outputting "." every second and prints done after 10 seconds.

here is my code, how can i read what the user inputs

```
t=$((5))
while [ $t -gt 0 ]; do
   echo -ne "."
   sleep 1
   : $((t--))
done
echo "done"
```

Comment: `t=$((5))` might as well be `t=5`, and `: $((t--))` is more simply written as `((t--))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `t=$((5))` to `t=$1`, which will assign the first argument to t.